# fatal exception asyncClass #3

Tags: android

```
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/TdsCore
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:359)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.example.zzzsqldb.ConnectionClass.CONN(ConnectionClass.java:34)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.example.zzzsqldb.MainActivity$DoLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:72)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at com.example.zzzsqldb.MainActivity$DoLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-05 00:07:20.204: E/AndroidRuntime(892):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: Post your working code

Comment: Can you please put the Async Class code.